# Making rhomboid with user defined angle in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing, vertices

I need to capture some buildings in ArcMap 10.3.

It works fine for perfectly rectangle buildings, but whenever some location has buildings with an angle like a rhomboid then it became very time consuming to first draw a rectangle and then edit its vertices to fit.

[image: this]

In the picture above blue ones are the correct building shape and green one is default rectangle shape. Note the angle difference.

Is there any extension, add-in, by which a user can define an angle first and whenever he makes a rectangle then it automatically edit its vertices to fit that particular angle?

Comment: I think that you will need to write some ArcPy code to do this within ArcMap.